# Neo4J - Get all paths without a repeating relationship type or node label

Tags: neo4j, cypher

From a given node, I need to return all variable length paths without a repeating relationship type or node label.

For example:

```
(:A)-[:r1]-(:B)

(:A)-[:r1]-(:C)-[:r2]-(:D)-[:r3]-(:E)
```

Comment: So, are you looking for some `Cypher` statements?  Your example, is that the expected output or input?  Maybe showing what the DB looks like and what your desired output is would help.  Is `A` a node label `:A`?  Is `r1` a relationship type `:r1`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained better. I am looking for some example Cypher statements.

So A, B, C, D & E are nodes of different labels, r1, r2 & r3 are different relationship types.

So, 

(a:A)-[r1:R1]-(b:B).

(a:A)-[r1:R1]-(c:C)-[r2:R2]-(d:D)-[r3:R3]-(e:E)

Comment: So, do you want to return what you have shown?... Or more, for example, `(:A)-[:r1]-(:C)`, etc.?

Comment: I'd like to return the paths if possible. As you've shown above: (:A)-[:r1]-(:C)

Comment: ... And `(:A)-[:r1]-(:C)-[:r2]-(:D)`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. All paths which fit the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was worked out for me  by some lovely people at Neo4J. It requires APOC.

```
MATCH p=(:StartingPoint)-[*1..3]->() WHERE size(apoc.coll.duplicates([x in relationships(p) | type(x)]))=0 AND size(apoc.coll.duplicates(apoc.coll.flatten([x in nodes(p) | labels(x)])))=0 RETURN p
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to use Cypher to evaluate this during traversal, and it seems to me filtering after getting all paths won't be efficient (though perhaps with a tree structure).

Your best bet is to implement your own custom procedure for this using the [traversal API](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/tutorial-traversal/).

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't think of anything efficient yet either.  What about looking at uniqueness of node labels and relationship types for successive depths of relationship?  Not sure how to do that though.

Comment: The uniqueness options with the traversal API are for specific nodes, not uniqueness of labels, so you'd need to code that logic in yourself with an Evaluator (and likewise make an Expander that you could use to keep track of visited relationship types to guide expansions).